# jquery: widget not destroying reapplying properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-widgets, jquery-ui-widget-factory

Here is jQuery widget code:

```
(function($){
    var _this,ele,parent;
    $.widget('test.talkWidget',{
        options:{
            a:'',
            b:''
        },
        destroy: function()
        {
            alert("asas");
            this.element
            .remove( ".talk" )
            .text( "" );
             $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call(this);
        },        
        _createTalkBox:function(){
    ele.find(".talk").prepend("<h1>talk box added</h1>");

        },
        _addReply:function(){alert("reply added");            
        },
        _attachEvent:function(){
            ele.on('keypress','textarea',function(e){
                if(e.keyCode===13){
                    alert($(this).val());_this._addReply();
                }
            });
            ele.on('click','.accept-check-off',function(e){                
                $(this).closest(".media").removeClass("accept-check-off accept-check-on");
                $(this).addClass("accept-check-on");
            });
            ele.on('click','.accept-check-on',function(e){
                $(this).closest(".media").removeClass("accept-check-off accept-check-on");
                $(this).addClass("accept-check-off");
            });            
        },
        _init:function(){
            ele=this.element;
            _this=this;
            parent=$("<div/>").addClass("talk").append("<br/><textarea class='form-control' rows='3'></textarea>");
            ele.html(parent);
            this._createTalkBox();
            this._attachEvent();
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Here i am calling this widget:

```
<div id="target"></div>

<button>Show Widget</button>
<button id="b2">Show normal Text</button>
```

Problem is 'Reply Added' is shown as many times as i click 'Show Widget' button. Actually it should be shown only as many times as I press ENTER key inside Teaxtarea . I think widget is not destroying itself properly.

[**Check jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ga7V/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widget is not destroying because there is no call to the widget factory `destroy()` function.

In your jsFiddle, each time you click on the "Show Widget" button, you :

- first remove the div `#target` content
- then call the widget with no param.

Calling the widget with no params multiple times result in :

- **first time** : call the factory `create()` function (which internally call the user defined `_create()` function, but you don't have some), then call the factory `init()` function (which internally call the user defined `_init()` function)
- **all other times** : only call the `init()` function

The problem is that you are binding events in the `_init()` function, so new events are binded each time you call the plugin, that is to say each time you click on your buttons. Plus you bind a click event (to call your plugin) using `button` selector, so the event is binded on the 2 buttons.

You should define a `_create()` function which will be called only once, to define actions needing to be done only once, such as event binding.

Have a look in this <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ga7V/3/)</kbd>, it should fit your needs. I simplified a little your code and add some explanations.

Comment: Yah its working in jsFiddle. Will give it try in my application and let you know

Comment: if I click `Show normal Text` button before `Show Widget` it shows `cannot call methods on talkWidget prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'`

Comment: You are right I forgot that :). You can check if the widget is initialized using `$target.is(':test-talkWidget')`. I updated the jsFiddle

Comment: It worked :). Well how will i know that a DIV contains any kind of custom widget. and how can I remove any kind of custom widget without specifying its name. Here i am specifying particular widget name `.is(':test-talkWidget')`

Comment: I don't think you can perform such thing, or i am not aware of.